# Future Perfect with "in" and "by"

Tags: tense

Let's look at this conversation:
A: My friend will start her studies in October.
B: I know! And I will have finished my studies by the end of June. (that's okay)

What about Person B saying "I will have finished my studies IN June?" Can I replace "by" with "in"? Is that okay or is it better to use Future Simple here? It's important for me to say I will finish my studies first.

Answer (score 1):

"By" June and "in" June mean two different things, so the "correct" word is the one that describes what you are trying to say.

"By" June means that your studies will be completed before the beginning of June. If you say, "my studies will be finished by June", and it's June 1st and your studies aren't done, then you're late.

"In" June means that your studies will be completed sometime during the month of June. If you say, "my studies will be finished in June", and your studies are done on May 30th, then you're early; and if your studies are done on July 1st, you're late. Any day from June 1 - June 30 is covered by "in June".

So which one you choose depends on what you mean. Either way, though, it's before October.